# free groups question

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

I need help to solve this question

> If $f:G_1\to G_2$ and $g:H_1\to H_2$ are homomorphisms of groups, then
>   there is a unique homomorphism $h:G_1*H_1\to G_2*H_2$ such that
>   $h_{G_1}=f$ and $h_{H_1}=g$

I don't have much experience solving free groups questions, I need a hint or something.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You didn't address a question asked to you in your last post, why would this be different?

Comment: @DonAntonio I will, be patient :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's about *free product* of groups. The free product of $G_1$ and $H_1$ is the freeest '*formal*' group that disjointly contains $G_1$ and $H_1$. Its elements are then written in the form $x_1y_1x_2y_2\dots$ for $x_i\in G_1,\,y_i\in H_1$ (it might start with a $H_1$-element as well, but that might also be considered with $x_1=e$ (the unit of $G_1$).

Let the mapping $h$ act on $G_1$ as $f$ and on $H_1$ as $g$.  That is, for a generic element $x_1y_1x_2y_2\dots$ of $G_1*H_1$, define
$$h(x_1y_1x_2y_2\dots):=f(x_1)g(y_1)f(x_2)g(y_2)\dots$$